# React Native - How to save map using AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, react-native

I try to save user inputs as a JS map using AsyncStorage in my React Native app.

It shows no errors when saving, but I got "[object Map]" when I tried to get the data back.

There is the simplified version of my user map. the actual User object has way more properties than this, but the ID is always same as the map key.

```
const dataKey = 'user-data';
let data = new Map();
data.set(1, { name: 'John', id: 1, title: 'Mr.' })
data.set(2, { name: 'Johanna', id: 2, title: 'Miss.' })
```

There is the code for saving the data.

```
async saveDate = (dataKey, data) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(dataKey, data.toString());
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

There will be more than 200 users in this map.

Any idea how to save complex data structure in react native?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of converting your data to a string you need to save it as JSON. Change

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem(dataKey, data.toString());
```

to

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem(dataKey, JSON.stringify(data));
```

See this link to the official documents for more details: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#mergeitem

Answer (score 0):

Like one of the other answers states, you need to save the data as JSON.

However, with you won't be able to simply convert `data` to JSON.  Instead you will need to spread the array entries of Map and pass that to `JSON.stringify()`.

So change

`await AsyncStorage.setItem(dataKey, data.toString());`

to

`await AsyncStorage.setItem(dataKey, JSON.stringify([...data]));`

And then when you want to get the item from Async you will need to convert it back to `Map`, i.e.

`const jsonData = AsyncStorage.getItem(dataKey)`

`const mapData = new Map(jsonData)`

Answer (score 0):

The provided answers will not quite work. You can't create the new Map after reading back json without parsing first. This works:

```
  saveData = async () => {
    const dataKey = 'user-data';
    let data = new Map();
    data.set(1, { name: 'John', id: 1, title: 'Mr.' })
    data.set(2, { name: 'Johanna', id: 2, title: 'Miss.' })

    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(dataKey, JSON.stringify([...data]));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    const jsonData = await AsyncStorage.getItem(dataKey)
    const parseData = JSON.parse(jsonData)
    const mapData = new Map(parseData)

    console.log(mapData);
    //get a list of IDs
    console.log(Array.from(mapData.keys()));



}
```

For 200 values this is a lot of overhead. I would consider using sprintf/sscanf libraries and just store a string, for instance one row of data per line.
This will only work if every row in the table has the same amount of elements and you don't change the layout. Of course it would all be on you to convert the string back to objects so you can recreate the Map. Just a thought!